# Can't run any single command related to android in Cordova in my Command Prompt?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, phonegap

I got below error regarding a node or npm once i run the command related to android like.

```
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
cordova build android
```

I have install below versions

Node : v8.12.0
npm  : 6.4.1
Android Studio Version : 3.1.4

I got below error

```
(node:6076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

[image]

Even I reinstalled the node, npm and android studio still got the same error.

What should I do ?

Comment: Please paste the related lines to android of your config.xml. Feels like the version you are trying to use does not exist....

Comment: Which lines you are talking about ?

Comment: <engine name="android" ...

Comment: Still getting same error after add engine in config.xml...please check..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7nG-SElDkVc5tq2d1p1kOprv2BNCgNB/view?usp=drivesdk